# How can I set a global variable inside a function using the Parcel Bundler?

Tags: javascript, global, parceljs

```
var myNum = 32;

function randomizer(limit) {
    let myNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * limit);

    console.log("myNum is " + myNum);
    console.log("Global myNum is " + window.myNum);
    if (window.myNum == undefined) {
        console.log("Can't access global object when using parcel bundler");
    }

    return myNum;
}
```

I get a console message saying `Global myNum is undefined`
Inside my `package.json` file I have  scripts line that reads;

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "parcel src/index.html",
    "build": "parcel build src/index.html"
  }
```

At the command line I am using `npm run dev`

Comment: I also tried using the array notation to access the global window object ie;   
 `console.log("Global myNum is " + window["myNum"];`

Answer (score 1):

<s>This appears to be [a bug](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/7270) in Parcel.</s>

**Update (12/2021):** The this bug is now fixed in parcel version `2.0.0-nightly.939` and later. It should be released in the next stable version of parcel after `2.0.1`.

The root cause is quite specific, so you might be able to work around it for now. It only happens when you shadow a global variable - e.g. you have `var myNum = 32`, and then, within a function scope you *re*-declare the a variable with the same name (e.g. `let myNum = <anything else>`). So if you can re-factor your code to avoid the shadowing, you can avoid the problem.